# Atribuir valores a um a variável

Tags: c, console, argumento

Tenho o seguinte programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a,b;
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int c;
    printf("%d",a+b);
    printf("%d",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Como faço para passar um valor para a variável global ou local via terminal?
Quando faço a saída do programa,quero que devolva logo a soma dado um comando via terminal, exemplo:

Compilo o programa:

```
cc exemplo.c -o exemplo
```

Depois para fazer o *output*:

```
./exemplo < a=1 b=2
```

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer, deseja pedir para o usuário digitar os dados?

Comment: eu introduzo o comando para fazer a saída do programa mas preciso de passar  os valores 1 e 2 para as variáveis a e b dentro do programa . Nao e possível fazer essa atriuicao directamente?./exemplo < a=1 b=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa pegar os dados do *array* de argumentos que o `main()` recebe. Pega cada um dos elementos sem pegar o 0 que é o nome do executável.

Como o argumento vem como *string*, precisa fazer uma conversão com [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Tem uma série de verificações que seria bom fazer, como saber se veio a quantidade de argumentos necessários, se a conversão do número deu certo e outras que possam ser úteis para o problema.

Não precisa de variáveis para apresentar a soma. Mas se for usar variáveis para outra coisa, não faça elas globais, quase nunca é necessário.

Não precisa dessa variável estática, só fiz assim pela limitação do ideone.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char *argv[] = { "app", "123", "456" }; //gambiarra pra simular a passagem de argumento pela linha de comando

int main(/*int argc, char *argv[] */) {
    printf("Soma: %ld", strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) + strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VakRgr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/oqbnqmkn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Strtol.c).

Comment: então nao existe forma ou comando que permita atribuir directamente um valor a uma variável sem ser pelo agrv[]

Comment: Não, como você imaginaria que pudesse ser?

Comment: nao tenho a certeza mas o meu professor acho que chamou uma função que estava dentro do programa com protótipo int soma(int a, int b) depois quando chamou no terminal (tenho duvidas aki) ./exemplo < soma 1 2 . E devolvia 3

Comment: Aí é outra questão, sem saber o que você precisa, fica difícil dar um resposta adequada.

Comment: mas eu nao estou a perceber como passa esses valores para essa função  int soma(int a, int b)

Comment: A sua pergunta não fala nada sobre isto.

Comment: pois mas era isso que queria dizer mas eu pensava que usava variáveis globais para receber os valores

Comment: A gente só pode responder o que foi perguntado, ninguém consegue entrar na sua cabeça e saber o que se passa aí, só o que está escrito pode ser respondido.

Answer (score 1):

Na sua função main, o **argc** representa o número de argumentos que estão sendo passados, enquanto o **argv** é um array com cada argumento. No seu exemplo, invocando `./exemplo 1 2`, seriam 3 argumentos (argc = 3), sendo eles:

argv[0] = "exemplo"

argv[1] = "1"

argv[2] = "2"

Desta forma, você pode usá-los assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a,b;
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int c;

    // string to long(string, endptr, base)
    // Converte o argv de String para Inteiro
    a = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    b = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);

    printf("%d",a+b);
    printf("%d",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Teste e me dê um feedback. Estou sem um compilador C no momento, mas edito se algo estiver fora quando eu testar.